# How does React.createRef() actually work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I went through [React docs for React Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html), and this what it says about `createRef()`

> createRef() receives the underlying DOM element as its current property. When the ref attribute is used on a custom class component, the ref object receives the mounted instance of the component as its current .

I have some questions on this. First have look at below component.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class ImageCard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.imageRef = React.createRef();
    console.log("Called in constructor", this.imageRef);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("Called when component did mount ", this.imageRef);
  }

  render() {
    const { description, urls } = this.props.image;
    return (
      <div>
        <img ref={this.imageRef} src={urls.regular} alt={description} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ImageCard;
```

So, in the constructor I created a *React Ref*, and assigned to a property called `imageRef`. And, in the `render()` method, I passed that  *React Ref* to `img` React element as an attribute as a `ref`.

*What does React Ref does here?*

`img` will eventually become an object which has a property called ref with value `this.imageRef`, how it receive `img` as it's current property?

If it was something like this `this.imageRef.current = img(object)`, It can be possibly. But I don't understand the above way i.e `ref={this.imageRef}`

Also, For both console statements this is the output that I get.

[image]

So, in the constructor current property is `null` that is valid. But, when I expand it, It has all properties that of `img` printed in `componentDidMount` i.e also `clinetHeght` *How*?

I don't know, If there is short explanation for this or someone have to right a full page. If that's too big to answer, external links or references would be helpful.

I also am not interested in nitty-gritty of library implementation, just an overview would be helpful so that I can use `React.createRef()` with confidence or without any doubt.

Comment: the object view in the console is live, so when you expand it, it reads the object from memory, which now has the `img` element as the value of that key.
If you want certainty about the state of an object when it's logged, you should deeply clone the object or convert it to a string (with JSON.stringify) before logging it

Comment: @FredStark Thanks, I read that now somewhere. Also, is it a browser feature or Or React attaches some observable on this?

Comment: Just a browser feature! The two current answers seem to cover everything I was trying to get across with much more detail

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For how `ref` gets assigned, you have to remember that JSX compiled down to plain old javascript.  A *very* simplified example of what is going on under the covers is something like this:

```js
function createRef(initialValue) {
    return {
        current: initialValue
    }
}

const root = document.getElementById('root');

function render(elementType, innerText, ref) {
    const el = document.createElement(elementType);
    if (ref) {
        ref.current = el;
    }
    el.innerText = innerText;
    root.replaceChildren(el);
}

const ref = createRef(null);
console.log(ref);
render('div', 'Hello World', ref);
console.log(ref);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

So basically - when you use `<img ref={this.imageRef} src={urls.regular} alt={description} />`, the `ref` is passed as a property, and in the function that renders it, it assigns the actual DOM node to `ref.current`.

Answer (score 6):

So, to answer your first question, React will assign the DOM element to the `current` property of the ref. In your case, that means that `this.imageRef.current` will be a reference to the image element as soon as the component has rendered.

The console output portion makes it a bit confusing, but it is not due to some magic done by React, but rather it is due to how the browser console handles objects whose properties change after the object has been logged. For example, if you run the following code in your console and then expand the output, you will see the same behavior your are seeing with the ref.

```js
const obj = { current: null }
console.log(obj)
obj.current = 'something'
```

Here is a screenshot of that what that looks like.

[image: console output example]