# Properties on a react returned jsx

Tags: reactjs

I see three (3) properties on a value my react component is returning namely keys, props and type and i am blank on how they work. I even see a fourth one called ref when i use the createElement method to create my DOM elements. Any help that would enlighten me on the area will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just a note - your questions are asking about the fundamental way that React works (pertaining to the use of the Virtual DOM and its component-based structure). I'll try to sum it up as much as possible and give links to resources that might be helpful.

- The `key` attribute relates to the way React uses the Virtual DOM and one of the reasons it works as fast as it does. In short, React supports the `key` attribute to improve its ability to **differentiate sibling elements/components** from each other and prevent re-painting the whole element tree if only one of the sibling changes. I suggest [reading further](https://key=%22hello%22) on this to better understand it.
- The `props` attribute relates to how React **passes data** from one component to another (usually from a parent component to a child component). Think of them as the arguments that you pass to a function - where the function is React's internal way of compiling your code and eventually rendering the DOM elements.
- `type` should be pretty straightforward - its used to determine the type of component/element (eg: `div`, or a React function component)
- The `ref` attribute relates to a way that you can store **references** to a particular element. By passing a React ref to a component/element's `ref` attribute, you're essentially storing access to that component/element through the React ref. There are some pretty [good explanations out there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65418747/how-does-react-createref-actually-work) about how it works on a conceptual level.

Note that my use of the word "component" refers to a [React components](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html), and "element" refers to the [DOM element](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp)

Comment: Thank you so much @ad2969 for a detailed clarity. I greatly appreciate. I have used used the key whilst mapping and the props as a way to reuse my components with different data, i don't know how to use them as part of a returned value that is: (const MyComponent = () => return (<div></div>).props ), it is my first time encountering such. Or i should not be concerned with it?

Comment: Oh I have figured out that the properties serves to give more information about returned value, that is the props it has, its type, whether it has any key or ref. I don't know if they have more functionality beyond that. Thank you for stimulating my thoughts.

Comment: For sure. In my experiences, I've not seen any real-life use for that pattern before: `(const MyComponent = () => return (<div></div>).props )`, so I don't think you should worry!